# Is there a way to map a Spring 3.0 MVC @RequestParam directly to a Java Bean?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Can this somehow work? do I have to use `@InitBinder` somehow?

```
public String myActionHandler(ModelMap model, @RequestParam MyPojoBean myBean){
    ...
}
```

1. I'm sure I've seen this somewhere,
   but I'm not sure where. Is
   there a simple code example for this?
2. If the above is possible, how
   can I catch the exception if the
   request doesen't match the Bean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register a custom editor in `initBinder`:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(MyPojoBean.class, new MyPojoEditor());
}

class MyPojoEditor extends java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport {
    @Override public String getAsText () {...}
    @Override public void setAsText (String s) {...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `@InitBinder` (see @Abdullah's answer), which is best if you only need to do this for a single class, or using a custom `WebArgumentResolver` (see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371315/how-to-implement-springs-3-1-mvcannotationdriven/5371892#5371892)), which is more general.